# Row clone not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a simple row. The following is my javascript code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
           var first_row = $('#Row2');
          first_row.clone().appendTo('#blacklistgrid');
     });
```

I am using the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/scxfvu7y/. But the button does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're aware the ids in the document must be unique?

Comment: Press F12 to open the developer console, and you will see why your code doesn't work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/scxfvu7y/5/

you had missed the jquery cdn

Answer (score 5):

- You are missing a reference to jQuery. Added to the version of the Fiddle below.
- You didn't close the call to `ready`.

  ```
  $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
            var first_row = $('#Row2');
          first_row.clone().appendTo('#blacklistgrid');
        });
  }); // <<< Add this
  ```

https://jsfiddle.net/scxfvu7y/4/

Answer (score 2):

You did not close the brackets of  the document ready and in your fiddle you don't load the jQuery library.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
           var first_row = $('#Row2');
          first_row.clone().appendTo('#blacklistgrid');
     });
  });
```

```css
td {
    padding-right: 15px
}
.space {
    padding-right: 75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <form action='/results' method="post">
   <table id="blacklistgrid">
        <tr id="Row1">
            <td>Week Number</td>
            <td>Oranges Sold</td>
            <td>Apples Sold</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Row2">
            <td>
                <input type="text"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="button" id="btnAdd">Add Row!</button>
    </br>
    </br>
    <input type="submit"></input>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to fix your fiddle with the following inorder to make it work.

1. Add the missing jquery reference to your fiddle.
2. close the document.ready function with end braces

I would suggest you to append the row to the table manually, since cloning the existing row always gives same id ie. ('#Row2') which may give trouble you at some point. So feel free to make use of this code inside the button Click event.

```
var lastrow_index = $('#blacklistgrid tr:last').attr('id').replace(/\D/g,'');
var currentrow_index = parseInt(lastrow_index + 1);
$('#blacklistgrid').append('<tr id="'+ currentrow_index  +'"><td><input type="text"/></td><td><input type="text"/></td><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>');
```

Hope this will help some one in the future.